# Get latest posts inside author looping

Tags: ghost-blog

I need to create a author list which will hold authors info as well as his/her latest 4 posts. My design will be look like this,

[image: image|545x500]

Here is my approch after searching google and digging in docs.

```
{{#get 'users' limit="all" include="count.posts,posts"}}
        {{#foreach users}}
            {{!-- user datas --}}
            {{name}} , {{bio}} // ... and so on

            {{!-- This user's posts --}}
            {{#foreach posts limit="3"}} 
                <a href="{{ url }}"> {{ title }} </a>
            {{/foreach}}

        {{/foreach}}
{{/get}}
```

I'm getting user data perfectly but can't get individual user's posts by this,

```
{{#foreach posts limit="3"}} 
     <a href="{{ url }}"> {{ title }} </a>
{{/foreach}}
```

Please make me correct.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for the posts of any given author:

```
{{#get 'users' limit="all" include="count.posts,posts"}}
   {{#foreach users}}              
        {{#get "posts" filter="authors:{{slug}}" limit="3"}}          
            {{#foreach posts}}
                 <a href="{{url}}"> {{title}} </a>
            {{/foreach}}            
          {{/get}}
    {{/foreach}}
{{/get}}
```